# How does one downgrading pyobjc to version 7.3?

Tags: python, macos, pynput, pyobjc

so i have been trying to write a script with pynput, however when i write:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
```

However i get the error:

```
dlsym(0x7fd5fac16b50, PyObjCObject_New): symbol not found
```

i read here (https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/1) that downgrading to pyobjc 7.3 worked for some people. how do i do that, using MacOS11.6, air M1 chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command for downgrading:

```
pip uninstall pynput
pip install pynput==7.3
```